# Composition series of a group

Tags: group-theory

If H is normal in a group G, where G has a composition series, then G has a composition series one of whose terms is H.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. I see that this is your first question. So I wanted to let you know a few things about MathSE. We like to know the sources of questions. We also like to know what you've tried on a problem. These sort of pleasantries usually result in more and better answers. Finally, I should add that posting questions in the imperative (i.e. Compute all such, Prove that...) is considered rude by some of the members, so it would be nice of you to change that wording. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Find a composition series for $H$ and one for $G/H$ and then try to *glue* them (using the fact that you probably know that there is a relationship between the set of normal subgroups of $G/H$ and the set of normal subgroups of $G$ which contain $H$...)